# creating a config file in grails

Tags: grails, redis

I am attempting to get a Grails project working but need help setting it up. I have an Ubuntu server running on a VM that has Redis installed. The project won't run unless I create a config file that can use Redis on the Ubuntu server. This is the settings I pulled down from GitHub located in the grails-app/conf/Config.groovy file.

http://snag.gy/eYhUY.jpg

I was told I need to create a separate config file that will override these parameters so my project will talk to the ubuntu server on my machine. This is a noob question but where do I create a config file? I can't seem to find a .grails folder. I know I'm suppose to reference my config file, once i've created one, in the `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy fil`e

http://snag.gy/SpGGt.jpg

Comment: Looking at the second screenshot, it seems you don't have grails configured for the project. I would suggest you to fix it if you are tying to run the project from IntelliJ.

Comment: is this done by configuring the grails sdk?

Comment: Click on the 'Configure Grails SDK' in the top-right corner of your second screenshot. This would probably ask you to select one of the Grails SDK that you may already have, otherwise you may have to download Grails.

Comment: just got it to work by pointing it to the grails install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the grails.config.locations specified in your Config.grooy and you can create any of those locations for creating the external Config file.

I prefer using the classpath route. Here is what I would do.

1. Create a folder (say appConfig) and place it in the tomcat/conf folder.
2. Add the application config file (proghorn-config.groovy in your case) to the folder, with the required configurations in the file.
3. Add the folder to the Tomcat classpath by updating either the tomcat/conf/catalina.properties or by creating the tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

Answer (score 0):

The location of the .grails folder depends upon the user account running the container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) which hosts your Grails application.

For example on Debian 6 running Tomcat 6.x the location is:

> /usr/share/tomcat6/.grails/

You can also use static paths as well:

> file:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/myspecific-config.groovy